# How to download AWS documentation using linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, curl, wget, aws

I tried to download AWS documentation using `wget` and `curl` commands. I realized and turned off robot and set Mozilla as browser header. But still failed to recursively download the entire documents.

Comment: Please explain exactly what's the issue. Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which documentation you're looking for, it might be easier just to install the [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and use the help features built into that.

Most of the docs are also [on github](https://github.com/awsdocs/) and available as PDFs so you could clone the repo or download the PDF.